# velocity in inertial and nontial frames

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, classical-mechanics, special-relativity, velocity

[image][image]

I got confused about the difference between the last term of both pictures. In the first one, we have w x r, but in the second we have w x r underlined. Does anyone have a better explanation? They should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same thing. Suppose you are standing still and your friend is moving at 5 meters per second on a train. Let's say your frame is the $K'$ frame and your friend's frame is the $K$ frame. Now you throw a ball in the direction of the trains motion at eight meters per second. Then the speed you see is $\mathbf{v}'=8\mathrm{m/s} \hat{x}$, where $\hat{x}$ is the direction of the train's motion.

Now let's suppose your friends picks the direction along the train tracks to be $\hat{y}$. Then he will see the ball's velocity to be $3 \mathrm{m/s} \hat{y}$. However, the author says to get $\mathbf{v}$, you must transform the $3 \mathrm{m/s} \hat{y}$ into your coordinate system. By that he means that the train's direction is $\hat{x}$ in your coordinate system, so you should really have $\mathbf{v} = 3 \mathrm{m/s} \hat{x}$.

Now given that your friends speed in your frame is $\mathbf{u}=5 \mathrm{m/s}\hat{x}$, we now have the desired formula $\mathbf{v}'=\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{u}$. Since $8\mathrm{m/s} \hat{x} =3 \mathrm{m/s} \hat{x} + 5 \mathrm{m/s}\hat{x}$. I left out the part with angular velocity because that is an extra detail.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your explanation of choosing coordinates at one's own free will against convention is great. I am now clear about this problem.

Comment: Another question I have is that I read Marion mechanics, and it says for the last term w x r underlined here is w x r. Do you know why? Are they the same? I have added another picture for you to see.

Comment: The two terms are the same. To see the reason behind the terms pretend you had a ball spinning on the ground. Now the two frames are your frame where you are standing still, and the frame of the ball. Now the relative velocity between these frames is zero, but some point which is stationary in the ball will appear to be moving according to you. So if the velocity is zero in the ball's coordinate system, the int will be $\mathbf{\omega} \times \mathbf{r}$ in your frame. This basically just says that points move around the axis of rotation and points farther away move faster.

Comment: Still you didn't explain why r and r underline in those two pictures are different. r means position observed in the rotational frame. r underlined mean r', observed in the noninertial frame. They are certainly different. Why you say they are the same.

Comment: I think underlining something means it is supposed to be expressed in the prime coordinates. So $\mathbf{r}$ is the coordinates of the position in the $K$ frame, and the underlined version is the coordinates in the $K'$ frame. So in the example with the train, $\mathbf{r}$ would have been $3 \mathrm{m/s} \hat{y}t$, and the underlined version would be $8\mathrm{m/s} \hat{x}t$. Thus the time derivative is the underlined $\vec{r}$ is $8\mathrm{m/s} \hat{x}$. Meanwhile the time derivative of $\mathbf{r}$ is $3 \mathrm{m/s} \hat{y}$. Continued...

Comment: Then the underlined version of the time derivative of $\mathbf{r}$ is $3 \mathrm{m/s} \hat{x}$, because to change coordinates of velocity to the $K'$ frame, you just need to change $\hat{y}$ to $\hat{x}$.